# Can the status line of the HTTP response be customized via Nginx or Apache HTTP Server?

Tags: apache, http, nginx

Typical [HTTP response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) consists of:

- a status line which includes the status code and reason message
  (e.g., HTTP/1.1 200 OK, which indicates that the client's request
  succeeded)
- response header fields (e.g., Content-Type: text/html)
- an empty line
- an optional message body

E.g

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 138
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close

<html>
  <head>
    <title>An Example Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am asking if there any way to customize the status line via Nginx or Apache Server configuration, so the **HTTP/1.1** will be replaced to **HTTP/N**, where **N** is a custom number (e.g. 2, 3, 4.4, etc.).
I know that developing a custom module for Nginx or Apache is a silver bullet in this case, but it would be better if there is another solution.

Comment: Both products implement the HTTP standard which says it must be 1.1. HTTP 2 is a totally different protocol.

Comment: @MSalters, I know that HTTP 2 is a completely different protocol. But my question is if it is possible to transform any HTTP/1.1 response the way described above.
So, this is more about Nginx/Apache features than about HTTP protocol versions.

Comment: You're missing the point of my comment. Why do you expect that someone made the effort to make nginx do the wrong thing?

Comment: @MSalters, I came to this question by the following. This is necessary to get around some network restrictions for HTTP/1.1 in those cases when the only HTTP/1.1 is blocked. If just replace HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 (once again, I know that the second version is different) most browsers display the content correctly.

Comment: You must not do that. You must use mod_http2 in apache, and some other conf in nginx ( I am not familiar). It just doesn't do anything good, only bad. HTTP/2 must only be used on https.